# Who are the writers of the stories in Fallout: New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm looking for names of specific people.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rp4HupvLXfg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkR9cPh5ECw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas) John R. Gonzalez as the writer of Fallout: New Vegas.

[Nukapedia has an article about him](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/John_R._Gonzalez) as well, but lists him as the Lead Creative Designer for New Vegas, and the Writer for the Honest Hearts DLC.

IMDB has a more comprehensive listing in its [writing credits for the game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706601/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers):

> John Gonzalez  ...     (lead writer)
>
> Chris Avellone
>   Eric Fenstermaker
>   Travis Stout
>
> Tess Treadwell     ...     (additional writing) &
>   George Ziets   ...     (additional writing) &
>   Jason Bergman  ...     (additional writing) &
>   Nick Breckon   ...     (additional writing) &
>   Matt Grandstaff    ...     (additional writing) &
>   Will Noble     ...     (additional writing) &
>   Andrew Scharf  ...     (additional writing)

According to IMDB, [he's also worked on](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4164525/?ref_=tt_ov_wr)

> Writer (3 credits)
>    2017 Horizon: Zero Dawn (Video Game)
>    2014 Middle-Earth: Shadow of Mordor (Video Game) (additional story)
>    2010 Fallout: New Vegas (Video Game) (lead writer)